# Excel VBA If rngcell= and next cell= then this cell= and next cell=

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to compare two ranges of cells, First objective is to see if there is any differences i.e. if this cell doesnt appear in this range. Second if the cell does appear has the next cell got this value.

Currently i have been able to output any cell in the first range that doesnt appear in the second:

```
For Each rngCell In Range("F7:F500")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H7:H500"), rngCell) = 0 Then
        Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
Next
```

I am very lost on how to approach the second part though so far I have tried the following:

```
For Each rngCell In Range("B6:B500")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H7:H500"), rngCell) = 0 Then
    Set r2 = Range("E7:E500")
    Else If (Range("H7:H500")) and WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r2("vault")) Then
    Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
```

Essentially, I am looking for an output with all the cells which are in the first range but not the second and all the cells that are in the first range and second but the next cell contains a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to try...

I like the Range/xlUp/Offset(1) to continuously add to the bottom of the list.

(needs preceeding Columns("O:O").ClearContents)

Correct me if I am wrong.

Lets clarify 2nd Objective --
  all the cells that are in the first range and second but the next cell contains a specific value.

```
  If  rngCell("B6:B500") IS in Range("H7:H500") 
  AND rngCell("B6:B500") IS in Range("E7:E500") MATCH (not CountIf) to get the row number
  AND if MatchedRowNum > 0 then
  AND "vault"            IS in Range("E7:E500").Offset(MatchedRowNum + 1)
```

Comment: So yes to clarify, for every cell in Row A that matches a cell in Row B check Row C to confirm the status. 


i.e. if cell A contains "HPT1234" and Row B has a cell that contains the same ("Cell B"), then it needs to check the cell to next to Cell B in row C ("Cell C"), which says the status i.e. "vault".  If the status in Cell C is "vault" it can then be ignored and move onto the next one. If it is anything other than "vault" i would like it to copy Cell A or Cell B as they contain the same to a new Row, Row D.

I hope this helps clarify

Comment: I notice in 1st Objective the use of CountIf > 0.  
For 2nd Objective, is there a possiblity of "HPT1234" appearing multiple times in Range("E7:E500") ?
If so, when should "HPT1234" be added to column "O"?  What if some but not all of "HPT1234" occurances are followed by "vault"? 
Do we need to search each occurance of "HPT1234" to see if we find the first non-vault item?  Requirements need to be clarified.

Comment: Well, I am very curious about how this could be written for the 2nd or 1st objective where HPT1234 could appear multiple times.  I can't think of an occurance in this scenario where HPT1234 could appear multiple times in Range("E7:E500"). So it can be based of the only time HPT1234 appears.